# Ruby on Rails devise issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have been trying to figure this out for way too long and i am hoping for some help here. I am new to Ruby and downloaded devise gem but when i try to run the sign up page it is giving me this error in my terminal:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-11 17:52:28 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_up"):
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.12) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (3.0ms)
```

I imagine this means i do not have a route for the sign up page. How do i set that up. I have looked online and tried almost everything and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you post the output from running 'rake routes' please?

Answer (score 1):

I would first make sure Devise is set up properly, per the instructions here... https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Specifically (after getting the Devise gem)...

```
rails generate devise:install
```

followed by...

```
rails generate devise MODEL
```

Where MODEL is often User.

After that your routes should just work assuming your links are correct. The sign up link alias is...

```
new_user_registration_path
```

Your routes.rb should have something like the following in it if it's set up properly...

```
devise_for :users
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users
```

maybe try running

```
rails g devise User
```

Hopefully you have already run

```
rails g devise:install
```